# Modular formula for binomial coefficients?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206669/division-in-modular-arithmetic-when-multiplicative-inverse-does-not-exist) and my answer.

The standard formula for binomial coefficients is well-known:
$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!\cdot (n-r)!}.$$
And the binomial theorem is one of the more prominent uses of binomial coefficients:
$$(x + y)^n = \sum_{r = 0}^n\binom nr x^{n-r}y^{r}.$$
However, when using the binomial theorem modulo some integer $k$ (i.e. when working with polynomials over $\Bbb Z_k$ rather than $\Bbb Z$), one encounters a problem putting these two things together. Specifically, if $n$ is large enough, the fraction in the formula for binomial coefficients is invalid, as the denominator will not be invertible modulo $k$.

Now, one could argue something along the following lines: $\binom nr$ as given in the formula represents an integer. One uses the formula over the integers to find the integer value of the binomial coefficient, and then reduce it modulo $k$. This approach will give the correct answer.

However, this doesn't sit entirely well with me. When expanding $(x + y)^n$ in $\Bbb Z_k[x, y]$, in any intermediate step as well as in the final answer, all coefficients are in $\Bbb Z_k$. The integers never really enter into this<sup>1</sup>.

So my question is this: **Is there a (relatively) compact formula<sup>2</sup> for $\binom nr$ modulo $k$?** Every arithmetic operation the formula describes ought to be valid modulo $k$, so most importantly there should be no factors of $k$ in any denominators.

A first attempt might be to clear away factors from the original formula. This way we get then:
$$
\binom nr = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}
$$
Once we get to this point, though, any more simplification of factors seems to be very difficult. And while this formula is a bit more robust (its validity is independent of the size of $n$, for one thing), it still won't work for large enough $r$.

---

<sup>1</sup> Many (most?) people, on some level, actually do the modular addition and multiplication required for this expansion the way described above: think integers first, then reduce modulo $k$ afterwards. But my point is that one does not *have* to do it that way.

<sup>2</sup> Say it should be simple enough that using it to calculate binomial coefficients up to around $n = 10$, or with $r$ close to $0$ or to $n$, with pen and paper should not be tedious, whatever that means. And while I don't expect there to be something as short as $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, I don't want there to be any problems fitting it in a single line.

---

**Edit:** I was made aware of [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) in the comments. This neatly solves the problem for prime $k$ (and by the Chinese remainder theorem for square-free $k$). I guess my remaining question is this: Can something be done for $k$ being the power of a prime? And if I'm being greedy, I personally think using the Chinese remainder theorem for calculations is a bit tedious at times. Can one make do without it? (This is in no way a requirement; a full solution using the CRT is completely fine. It might also be just me not having found an algorithm I'm comfortable with, which is another issue enteirely.)

Comment: Does a look in here (this one uses Lucas'  theorem) help?:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537360/calculating-binomial-coefficient-nck-for-large-n-k

Comment: @Andreas I was unaware of Lucas' theorem. That neatly solves the problem for prime $k$ (and by the Chinese remainder theorem for square-free $k$).

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem#cite_note-3 for a recipe for prime powers.  I have not looked at this in detail.

Comment: See [Lucas' Theorem for Prime Powers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669813801229).